# Are there any ways to actually stop awaited long-running asyncio Task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

If there is a long-running background task, `cancel()` method does not work as I expected (does not work at all). And I cannot find a way to actually stop the task, is that even possible or am I missing something about `asyncio` work?

Documentation says:
"`Task.cancel()` does not guarantee that the Task will be cancelled."

But as far as I understand it is due to possibility of coroutine handling the `CancelledError` exception and suppressing cancelation which is not my case.

I tried to run sample code beneath and got infinite loop running forever, `cancel()` there does not work.
My understanding here is that hitting that `await asyncio.sleep(1)` on the next asyncio event loop iteration should trigger task cancellation, but it is not happening.
How can I make already awaited `background_task` stop?

```
async def background_task():
    while True:
        print('doing something')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(background_task())
    await task
    task.cancel()
    print('Done!')


asyncio.run(main())
```

The output would be:

```
doing something
doing something
doing something
doing something
doing something
doing something
...
```

Comment: `task.cancel()` is not called in your code until the task is done, i.e. never. Maybe you meant to first call `task.cancel()` and then `await task`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess you are right that it's not getting called, but I don't get why, because its `Task` which supposed to run in the background and shouldn't be blocking because of the `await`s. As I mentioned in my question, maybe its my bad understanding of async execution. But what's the point in that `cancel()` method then? To cancel the task before it started of after it finished? Would be a strange instrument.

Comment: `await task` literally means "do not execute the code below before `task` is finished". If you don't want to wait for it to be finished, don't use `await`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right, it was just my bad understanding of async execution. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its not possible in my case. If you await a long-running task - the caller will wait for task completion and therefore block (thanks to @mkrieger1
for the explanation in comments). To actually stop the task, you should either modify it and add some event or flag like @zShadowSkilled mentioned, or run it with `asyncio.wait_for()` by specifying a timeout.

Comment: There are other ways as well, that do not entail modifying the task.  You can create a third task that cancels the second one, or you can create a function callback with  asyncio.loop.call_soon (or loop.call_at).

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the script like this to make it work like you're expecting:

```
import asyncio

async def background_task(stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print('doing something')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    stop_event = asyncio.Event()
    task = asyncio.create_task(background_task(stop_event))
    # Simulate running the task for some time
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    stop_event.set() # Set the event to stop the background_task
    await task # Await the task to complete
    print('Done!')

asyncio.run(main())
```

In this modified code, the `background_task` coroutine is checking for an Event object (`stop_event`); when this event is set (`stop_event.set()`), the loop within the `background_task` will stop because of the condition, `while not stop_event.is_set()`. This allows the task to gracefully exit without relying solely on task cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I was hoping to cancel the task without making any changes to it, maybe somebody will explain to me why the `cancel()` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `background_task()` is a never-ending coroutine the line `task.cancel()` and `print('Done!')` never being called.

The following workaround might be the thing you are looking for — adding another coroutine to cancel the background task:

```py
import asyncio

async def background_task():
    while True:
        print('doing something')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def cancel_coroutine(task):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    task.cancel()

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(background_task())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(cancel_coroutine(task1))
    await task1
    await task2

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print("Done!")
```

Out:

```
doing something
doing something
doing something
Done!
```

---

Or changing the order of the awaits without needing another coro as follows:

```py
async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(background_task())
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    task.cancel()
    await task

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print("Done!")
```